# Using of 100s of Binary features in regression model

Tags: scikit-learn, regression, feature-selection, cross-validation

I have 100s of columns with binary values [0, 1] plus some extra columns without binary values. I am trying to do regression model but the model performance is very low. For non-binary features, I have used PCA to decrease the dimension of it. I don't think its appropriate to use PCA for binary values. I am guessing, its because of the large number of binary columns, the model isnt doing great. What can be done on this kind of situation ? I have tested with almost all of the regression model available in sklearn.

What approach I could take to improve the model performance ? Any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

An approach worth exploring for dimensional reduction of these binary features would be [Multiple Correspondence Analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_correspondence_analysis) (Python libraries such as [Prince](https://github.com/MaxHalford/prince) and [mca](https://pypi.org/project/mca/) are available), which is similar to PCA but deals with nominal categorical variables. Here is an [excellent answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/16331/doing-principal-component-analysis-or-factor-analysis-on-binary-data) on applicability of PCA and factor analysis to binary features and [another one](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/159705/would-pca-work-for-boolean-binary-data-types) on the same topic.